# Anyone know how to render cgm files in XEP?

Tags: xsl-fo

Apparently XEP has no support for cgm files, so i was wondering if anyone knows of any plugins or anything that could be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no plugins that I know of. What I've done in the past is to have a separate SVG version of the graphic and use that. I modified the NDATA ENTITY declarations to point to the SVG when the XML was transformed to XSL-FO.

You might be able to convert the CGM to SVG in your processing pipeline, but I'm not sure what kind of performance impact that would be and I'm not sure what you'd use to do the conversion.

Antenna House does support CGM (extra $$), but I've never used it.